# Why Geo-block Sites Without Secure Information?

Tags: geolocation

I am an American software developer living in Honduras. We run an orphanage in this country, and my job funds most of it. I frequently do business, making purchases or gathering information about vendors, online. I understand blocking countries from financial sites that don't do business in the country trying to access it, but banks rarely do that. What I don't understand is companies like hospitals or even governmental sites blocking access. In the former case we recently had a medical emergency that we had to fly stateside for. In the latter case we have a condo in Texas that we need to pay property taxes on. In both cases, basic information was blocked that is otherwise available to anyone in the USA.

Why do companies block potential and current customers from non-secure information based on the country of requestor?

Comment: it lowers the threat landscape for the site to limit it to only those countries that are expected to access it